# Ruby: max of enumerize throw `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example we have a class.

```
class Foo
  def initialize(a)
    @a = a
  end

  def a
    @a
  end
end
```

we use it like

```
[Foo.new(1), Foo.new(2)].max(&:a)
=> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

but

```
[Foo.new(1), Foo.new(2)].max { |e| e.a }
```

works fine.

WHY?

Comment: Interesting, especially taking into account the fact that `max` DOES accept an argument (if you define `<=>` method for Foo you should be able to call `[<list of Foos>].max(n)` to get n largest Foos...). It looks to me like some parser's gotcha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> [Foo.new(1), Foo.new(2)].max { |e| e.a }
> ```
>
> works fine.

No, it doesn't. It may return a wrong value when your input is not in a strictly ascending order (such as `[Foo.new(3), Foo.new(2)]`).

The block to `max` will be given two arguments and it should `<=>` them.

Did you mean `.max_by(&:a)` instead?

Answer (score 2):

```rb
# ruby doc for Array (https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-max)
max → obj
max {|a, b| block} → obj
```

`[Foo.new(1), Foo.new(2)].max(&:a)`
match the first "max" without argument.

`[Foo.new(1), Foo.new(2)].max { |e| e.a }`
the second uses the block to return a <=> b.

```rb
[Foo.new(3), Foo.new(2)].max { |e| e.a }
# would not get the expect result
```

Answer (score 2):

Ref [`max`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-i-max) of a an array

```
max_foo = [Foo.new(1), Foo.new(2)].max { |c, d| c.a <=> d.a } 
max_foo.inspect # will return max array element after comparing something like #<Foo:0x00007fe3cb84e318 @a=2>
max_foo.a # will return 2
```

In single line

```
max_foo = [Foo.new(1), Foo.new(2)].map(&:a).max # Will return 2
```

Explaining `max` method in details below

1. Block {|a, b| block}
   `Returns the object in ary with the maximum value. The first form assumes all objects implement Comparable; the second uses the block to return a <=> b.`

   ```
    2.6.5 :030 > %w(gzabc def ghi abcdef).max {|a,b| a.length <=> b.length }
     => "abcdef"
   ```
2. without any parameter or block, Returns the maximum `element` of an array

   ```
   2.6.5 :021 > (4..9).to_a.max
   => 9
   2.6.5 :022 > [500, 200, 150, 300].max
   => 500
   2.6.5 :023 > [1,2,3,9,8,7,4,5,6].max
   => 9
   2.6.5 :027 > %w(gzabc def ghi abc).max
   => "gzabc"
   ```
3. Number n `If the n argument is given, maximum n elements are returned as an array.`

   ```
    2.6.5 :011 > (4..9).to_a.max(2) # Returns first two max values from given `n` i.e 2 here
     => [9, 8]
    2.6.5 :012 > [1,2,3,9,8,7,4,5,6].max(3) # Returns first three max values from given `n` i.e 3 here
     => [9, 8, 7]
    2.6.5 :013 > [500, 200, 150, 300].max(1) # Even if the value of `n` is 1 it will return array
     => [500]
    2.6.5 :014 > [500, 200, 150, 300].max(0)
     => []
     2.6.5 :028 > %w(gzabc def ghi abc).max(2)
     => ["gzabc", "ghi"]
   ```

Comment: `max_foo = [Foo.new(1), Foo.new(2)].map(&:a).max` - this returns max a, not max foo.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev : Yes, this is single line code for the previous line i.e. `max_foo.a` which returns 2. For max foo I already mentioned `max_foo = [Foo.new(1), Foo.new(2)].max { |c, d| c.a <=> d.a }`. But I'll update answer again for more clarification.